# React-Native Navigator is deprecated and has been removed from this package

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-navigation

I get the following error.

Navigator is deprecated and has been removed from this package. It can now be installed and imported from **react-native-deprecated-custom-components** instead of react-native. Learn about alternative navigation solutions at http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigation.html

Then I would update react-native-deprecated-custom-components package but issue not solved

Package.Json

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.6",
    "react-native": "0.44.2",
    "react-native-deprecated-custom-components": "^0.1.0",
    "sendbird": "^3.0.30"
},
```

main.js

```
var React = require('react-native')
var {
  Navigator,
  StyleSheet
} = React;

var Login = require('./components/login');

import NavigationExperimental from 'react-native-deprecated-custom-components';

var ROUTES = {
  login: Login
};

module.exports = React.createClass({
  renderScene: function(route, navigator) {
    var Component = ROUTES[route.name];
    return <Component route={route} navigator={navigator} />;
  },
  render: function() {
    return (

      <NavigationExperimental.Navigator
        style={ styles.container }
        initialRoute={ {name: 'login'} }
        renderScene={this.renderScene}
        configureScene={ () => { return Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromRight; } }
      />
    );
  }
});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1
  }
});
```

Any one let me know to solve this issue

Comment: You should not use the deprecated Navigator, but instead one of the alternatives mentioned in the [link](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigation.html) you shared.

Comment: Yes, But this error show again

Comment: I fixed the issue @Nora

Comment: how do u fix it @arunkumar ?

Comment: see my answer @viji

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ive use below code to fix my issue

main.js

```
var React = require('react-native')
var {
  Navigator,
  StyleSheet
} = React;

var Login = require('./components/login');

import NavigationExperimental from 'react-native-deprecated-custom-components';

var ROUTES = {
  login: Login
};

module.exports = React.createClass({
  renderScene: function(route, navigator) {
    var Component = ROUTES[route.name];
    return <Component route={route} navigator={navigator} />;
  },
  render: function() {
    return (

      <NavigationExperimental.Navigator
        style={ styles.container }
        initialRoute={ {name: 'login'} }
        renderScene={this.renderScene}
        configureScene={ () => { return NavigationExperimental.Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromRight; } }
      />
    );
  }
});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1
  }
});
```

Any one let me know to solve this issue

I've change the lines

```
configureScene={ () => { return NavigationExperimental.Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromRight; } }
```

To

```
configureScene={ () => { return NavigationExperimental.Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromRight; } }
```

Fix my issue

Answer (score 4):

You should use  Stack Navigator now

```
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

const SimpleApp = StackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
  Chat: { screen: ChatScreen },
});

 <Button
          onPress={() => navigate('Chat')}
          title="Chat with Lucy"
        />
```

reference : https://reactnavigation.org/docs/intro/

Comment: Did not work for me. I am using `react-native` v53 and `react-navigation` 1.0.3

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is seeing this while not even trying to use `Navigator`, it’s possibly because you’ve got an `import` line like

`import * as RN from 'react-native'`

(Webstorm in particular has a habit of auto-inserting these)

This calls the `get`ters for all of RN’s exports, triggering the error for `Navigator`. Instead use:

`import {Things, You, Need} from 'react-native'`

Comment: I found an 'import ReactNative, {View, Text} from 'react-native' in my source code that caused this error also. Thanks!